# De-tangling logs for tasks running in Node JS

Tags: node.js, logging, asynchronous

Saving a new row kicks off 2 async jobs. I'm trying to debug ONE of the background jobs as they run through some shared model code. The problem is, if I add logging to debug any of the shared code, suddenly it is tangled and looks like:

```
15:36:42 worker.1 | Running SQL "select count() .."  (job #1)
15:36:42 worker.1 | Running SQL "select * .."        (job #2)
15:36:42 worker.1 | Got to part 2 of the code        (job #1)
15:36:42 worker.1 | Got to part 3 of the code        (job #1)
15:36:42 worker.1 | Got to part 2 of the code        (job #2)
15:36:42 worker.1 | Got to part 3 of the code        (job #2)
15:36:42 worker.1 | Got to part 4 of the code        (job #1)
15:36:42 worker.1 | Job failed                       (job #2)
15:36:42 worker.1 | Job complete                     (job #1)
```

Except the "job #2" labels are not possible in reality. I just added those to illustrate the confusion.

I want to filter out all the log lines that don't occur as a result of `job #2`

Both jobs share the same `process.pid` - "should" they be separate processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible to isolate job 2 and run it independent of job1, (or maybe just provide whatever input your system requires to create a job that produces the results you'd like to debug.)

If not could you label you `async jobs`. If you can give each one of your jobs a unique id which is initialized early in the chain and passed throughout the chain then you can grep your log based on that id.

Labeling your code should definitely be a possibility in reality, it just might require a restructuring or refactoring of your code.

Another option is to have a worker pool that you offload your jobs to, which would isolate each job to a worker, but might not be necessary, and would certainly add complexity to your program.

Comment: Isolating the job is possible. I think in this instance I want to see if there are side affects from running in parallel, though. I really like the idea of making up a UUID for the job at the beginning and having it be part of the state that's passed along through the Promises. Thanks!